# Javascript Range, Variance, and Standard Deviation Functions

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So, I've been recently tasked to do a few calculations and to build a custom JS statistics library. The only 3 things I have left are to create functions for the range, variance, and standard deviation. What I'm doing here is passing my array (x) into the js functions, but they keep coming up blank. Am I doing something wrong?

```js
function findSum(x)
{
 var sum = 0;
 for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
 {
  sum = sum + x[i];
 }
 return sum;
};

function findMean(x)
{
return findSum(x) / x.length;
};

function findMedian(x) 
{
    x.sort( function(a,b) {return a - b;} );

    var half = Math.floor(x.length/2);

    if(x.length % 2)
        return x[half];
    else
        return (x[half-1] + x[half]) / 2.0;
}

// Ascending functions for sort
function ascNum(a, b) { return a - b; }

function clip(arg, min, max) {
  return Math.max(min, Math.min(arg, max));
};


function findMode(x) 
{
  var arrLen = x.length;
  var _arr = x.slice().sort(ascNum);
  var count = 1;
  var maxCount = 0;
  var numMaxCount = 0;
  var mode_arr = [];
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
    if (_arr[i] === _arr[i + 1]) {
      count++;
    } else {
      if (count > maxCount) {
        mode_arr = [_arr[i]];
        maxCount = count;
        numMaxCount = 0;
      }
      // are there multiple max counts
      else if (count === maxCount) {
        mode_arr.push(_arr[i]);
        numMaxCount++;
      }
      // resetting count for new value in array
      count = 1;
    }
  }

  return numMaxCount === 0 ? mode_arr[0] : mode_arr;
};

function findRange(x)
{
 x.sort( function (a, b) {return a-b;} );
}

function findVariance(x) {
  var mean = findMean(x);
  return findMean(array.map(findSum(sum)) {
   return Math.pow(sum - mean, 2);
  }));
 },
 
function findStandardDeviation(x) 
{
  return Math.sqrt(findVariance(x));
};
```

The HTML code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <h1>Statistical Calculations</h1>

    <title>Calculating Stats</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src='Stats.js'></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function addNumber()
    {
        var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
        var list = document.getElementById('list');
        var option = document.createElement('OPTION');
        list.options.add(option);
        option.text = input;
    }

    function getStatistics()
    {
        var list = new Array();
        var select = document.getElementById('list');
        for(i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++)
        {
            list[i] = parseInt(select.options[i].text);
        }
        document.getElementById('summation').value =findSum(list);
        document.getElementById('mean').value = findMean(list);
        document.getElementById('median').value = findMedian(list);
        document.getElementById('mode').value = findMode(list);
        document.getElementById('variance').value = findVariance(list);
        document.getElementById('standardDev').value = findStandardDeviation(list);
        document.getElementById('range').value = findRange(list);
        document.getElementById('max').value = findMax(list);
        document.getElementById('min').value = findMin(list);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Input Number:</td><td><input type='text' id='input'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colpsan='2'><input type='button' value='Add Number' onClick='addNumber()'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>
            <select id='list' size='5'>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
                <td colpsan='2'><input type='button' value='Calculate!' onClick='getStatistics()'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Summation:</td><td><input type='text' id='summation' readonly></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Mean:</td><td><input type='text' id='mean' readonly></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
                <td>Median:</td><td><input type='text' id='median' readonly>    </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
                <td>Mode:</td><td><input type='text' id='mode' readonly></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>               
         <td>Max:</td><td><input type='text' id='max' readonly></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>               
         <td>Min:</td><td><input type='text' id='min' readonly></td>
        </tr>


    <tr>
                <td>Range:</td><td><input type='text' id='range' readonly></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
                <td>Variance:</td><td><input type='text' id='variance' readonly></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
                <td>Standard Deviation:</td><td><input type='text' id='standardDev' readonly></td>
        </tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The last 3 seem to do absolutely nothing, and I've been bashing my head in for the last few days trying to figure it out. If anyone could help sort my functions out into working order, it'd be greatly appreciated! I'm sure that the array has been passing into the functions correctly, seeing as the first 4 functions obviously worked.

Comment: Check the developer console (click "Run code snippet") to see the mistake with range, also you seem to be missing some `return` statements. Last function is anonymous - missing a name? Did you really spend a few days on that? :)

Comment: Fixed. I've just been slowly working on it and have tried to create functions that would calculate the range (the other examples online only use explicitly defined arrays), variance, and standard deviation of the numbers input by the user into the array. I've been implementing and adjusting every example I've come across, but to no avail.

Comment: Where would I be missing return statements? I feel like there are more than enough in there... :c

Comment: You're missing it in `getRange`.

Comment: The *findSum* function assumes the values are numbers, but the sorting functions assume they're strings. If they're not numbers, *findSum* will return incorrect results. If they are numbers, *sort* doesn't need a sort function (and will run a lot faster without it).

Comment: @RobG, you're talking about the x.sort, or the ascNum?

Comment: @Tak—I'm just pointing out an inconsistency in the design. In one place it's "string safe" but not in another, so can the values be strings or must they be numbers?